# How to create Transparent background?

Tags: android

I have LinearLayout and one of it attribute is android:background="@drawable/bgImg"
I want to create the background to be transparent. Do someone have any clue about this issue?
Thanks

Comment: try this android:background="#00000000"

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to make the layout transparent just use
android:background="#00000000"

But if you want to make the application transparent (the area which is not occupied by app will be transparent) add style in manifest.xml, like following

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
```

Comment: Assume you meant to add `<activity android:name=".SomeActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove that `android:background="@drawable/bgImg"` attr from the `LinearLayout` declaration.

Comment: Or change it to @android:color/transparent if you need to override an existing style or theme.